# Multiple Projects on a single VCS root causing pending

Tags: svn, teamcity

I've got 2 entirely separate projects that both rely on the the same base project and shared nuget packages. For that reason I have little choice but to have a single VCS root that will ensure I have all the files needed.

I've managed to configure each project in TeamCity to work with the needed csproj files and trigger correctly. However if I commit something for Project A that Project B doesn't care about it will still show as 'Pending(x)' even though they will never get triggered with that project's configuration.

It goes away when I commit something that Project B -does- care about, but it is annoying to look at. So is there a way to configure it to not even look at changes in files from Project A?

[image: Pending example]

This is the trigger for project A:

```
-:root=SVN:.
+:Web/**
+:Library/**
```

And this is the trigger for project B:

```
-:root=SVN:.
+:Client/**
+:Library/**
```

I'm using Subversion for my VC if that would make any difference to help in configuring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a single VCS root, but configure checkout rules instead of VCS triggers. If you edit the build configuration and go under VCS settings select "view checkout rules". For the first project enter:

```
+:Web/**
+:Library/**
```

This will then mean the build doesn't know anything about /Client and can't tell you changes are pending. If you make this change, you no longer need to restrict the VCS trigger as it will be pre-filtered to only look at these folders.

You will need to make a similar change to the second build configuration to achieve the same.

Comment: The checkout rules go for the VCS root as a whole, so changing one made it affect both of the projects. However with the knowledge of the checkout process I decided on using 2 roots with configured checkout rules, it now works properly the way I want it. While not directly the answer it did lead me to a solution, so marking you up.